# How can we show taps on the device when running XCUITests

Tags: ios, swift, automated-tests, xcuitest

While running a UI test in XCUITest, we are not able to know where the tap is happening exactly on an iOS device since the taps are not shown by default. There is a way to show taps as mentioned in [this article](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-show-touches-on-ios-device-e0d9f00cc6f5).
How can we do the same programmatically? Is there any other way to know which UI element is receiving the tap? or maybe a swipe action?

Comment: This is not possible programatically. You will have to turn on it from setting as mention in blog you shared.